# R BiocManager::install() fails to read temp files

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install some packages (quite basic ones actually) for R 3.6, but I'm getting a fairly strange error message from `BiocManager::install()`:

```
BiocManager::install("XML", destdir = "/my/dir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/")
error: could not load shared object '/my/dir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-XML/00new/XML/libs/XML.so':
libicui18n.so.58: Could not open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

(Translated from french - could be approximate)

Does this mean that R can't write in `/my/dir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/`? That would be my first idea but I really don't know.

**EDIT:**

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_NUMERIC=C            LC_TIME=C              
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8  LC_MONETARY=C           LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C              LC_NAME=C               LC_ADDRESS=C           
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C          LC_MEASUREMENT=C        LC_IDENTIFICATION=C    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocManager_1.30.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2 tools_3.6.2
```

Comment: I don't think it is what the error message is telling you. It may be worth sharing the original command line you were using along with your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @KevinCazelles by command line, you mean what I typed into my shell to pull up R? cause it was just `R`. For the install, it is included in the original post.

Comment: I guess I am confused, I thought you've used `install.packages()` but actually, you used `BiocManager::install("XML", destdir = "/my/dir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/")`, is that correct?

Comment: @KevinCazelles correct, my bad, I thought that `BiocManager::install()` was just a different version of `install.packages`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Just want to be sure. Did you actually use `/my/dir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/` on purpose? Is `/my/dir/` the actual path or one you've made up for your post?

Comment: @KevinCazelles I made it up, the real path is `/home/my.name/...` but I preferred not putting my name in a public post like that

Comment: I guess it's a system configuration problem, this seems related https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/219 there is a solution there, hope this could help.

Comment: @KevinCazelles Yep, that worked. If you write it out into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Did you export the anaconda lib path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a configuration problem, there is a fix available at github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/219.